# Spring boot upgrade - codehaus gmavenplus-plugin throwing missing dependency javax.servlet.http.HttpUpgradeHandler exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, groovy

Our application is built on legacy spring boot 1 and tomcat 7. We have 2 types of test suites - Junits(Java) and Integration Test(Written in Groovy). We use below plugin to compile our groovy tests.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>${groovyVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <!-- testGenerateStubs allows us to reference Groovy classes from Java tests -->
                        <goal>testGenerateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <testSources>
                    <testSource>
                        <directory>src/test/groovy</directory>
                    </testSource>
                    <testSource>
                        <directory>src/test-integration/java</directory>
                        <directory>src/test-integration/groovy</directory>
                    </testSource>
                </testSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

We are recently doing a major upgrade to spring boot 2.7.1 and in process of removing deprecated methods - code refactoring etc. We are almost done with it but only today found an issue with goal "testCompile" of gmavenplus-plugin. It is throwing below error.

```
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:1.2:testCompile (default)
[INFO] Using Groovy 2.4.6 to perform testCompile.
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.2:testCompile (default) on project trta-tds: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.: InvocationTargetException: Unable to load class org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest due to missing dependency javax/servlet/http/HttpUpgradeHandler
```

We are suspecting this could be tomcat 7 issue but again we do not see tomcat being used for "testCompile" goal. We are on tight timeline. Please let us know your suggestions/solutions.

Comment: having a similar issue. just checking: did you manage to solve Anish?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case helps update javax.servlet-api to the newest version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```